# Credit freeze and affect on perception as credit risk

Tags: credit, credit-report, credit-history, identity-theft

In light of the [Equifax hack](https://www.cnbc.com/2017/09/07/credit-reporting-firm-equifax-says-cybersecurity-incident-could-potentially-affect-143-million-us-consumers.html) I keep reading that people should apply a credit freeze on themselves at the 3 main bureaus. However, someone told me that their mortgage consultant said that placing a credit freeze on yourself makes you look like a risky candidate for future credit approvals/mortgages.

I researched all over, but I couldn't find any evidence to confirm this. Is it true that if you apply a credit freeze on yourself, you will be viewed as a risky candidate for future mortgage or credit approvals?

Comment: Welcome to Money.SE, good first question.

Comment: It's also hearsay *of* hearsay, so you're totally playing the [game of telephone here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_whispers).  The consultant could be an idiot, he could have expressed himself incorrectly, the mutual friend misheard or remapped the meaning to his understanding, your friend's recollection may have faded, you may have misunderstood him, etc. etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From personal experience, I would say no. I was not viewed as a "risky" candidate. However, I did have to go through extra hoops to prove my identity.